# Solving for stationary points for questions of the following type

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

> How do you solve questions like $f(x,y) = x^2y + y^3x -xy$ for stationary points?

A link to an educational resource that goes over this would be very helpful as well, as I don't even know what this type of problem is called so I don't know what to search for.

**Note:** I apologize for the vagueness, I'm currently in an applied optimization class that up to this point has only required linear algebra. The final week requires some advanced calculus and it has been a very long time since I have done calculus and I remember very little. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Differentiate the function and the find its roots. In other words, solve the equation $$f'(x,y)=0$$